# What does #[macro_use] before an extern crate statement mean?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

In Rust, I sometimes see `#[macro_use]` before an `extern crate` statement:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate gotham_derive;
```

What does this do compared to not having `#[macro_use]`?

```
extern crate gotham_derive;
```

Comment: I'm not greatly familiar with Rust's macros, but [it appears](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/macros/macro-changes.html#macro_rules-style-macros) that `#[macro_use]` was required in Rust 2015 to inform the compiler that you were using macros defined inside the crate.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It means to import ("use") the macros from the crate.

As of [Rust 1.30](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1300-2018-10-25), this syntax is no longer generally needed and you can use the standard `use` keyword instead.

Review the [macros chapter from the first edition of *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.29.0/book/first-edition/macros.html?highlight=macro_use#scoping-and-macro-importexport) for more detail.

Comment: I tried using 1use serde_derive;` instead of `#[macro_use] extern crate serde_derive;` but it failed!

Comment: @HasanAYousef `use serde_derive;` is a no-op, like any `use` statement that doesn't have a `::` in it. You probably wanted `use serde_derive::{Deserialize, Serialize};` or similar.

Answer (score 16):

As Shepmaster already explained, in newer Rust versions (edition 2018+) this syntax is no longer needed. However, there are still cases when it might come in handy, like **global macro imports**. Here is an excerpt from [Rocket's documentation](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/overview/), which explains why they prefer having `#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;` in their code:

> Throughout this guide and the majority of Rocket's documentation, we
> import rocket explicitly with `#[macro_use]` even though the Rust 2018
> edition makes explicitly importing crates optional. However,
> explicitly importing with `#[macro_use]` imports macros globally,
> allowing you to use Rocket's macros anywhere in your application
> without importing them explicitly.
>
> You may instead prefer to import macros explicitly or refer to them
> with absolute paths: `use rocket::get;` or `#[rocket::get]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
// all the rockets macros import globally. 
//you can use rocket macros anywhere in your application
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;
```