# How to declare a `use` in `main.rs` that is visible to the whole?

Tags: rust

I have a rust project with `main.rs`, some other modules in the `main.rs` level and several submodules underneath. I use the `anyhow` crate in almost all of them.

Is there a clean way to declare `use anyhow;` only *once* (probably in `main.rs`?) without the need to redclare its usage in every single mod/file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `anyhow` itself should be accessible without `use` (as of Edition 2018), because this is a crate name. If you mean to import something within that crate for your entire project (`use anyhow::Context;`), then no, there is no standard¹ way to have that.

Each module has its own scope for such symbols, which are imported via `use`. The one exception is in the standard preludes, defined by the compiler itself. These are what enable you to use `Copy`, `Result`, and others without having to import them explicitly. However, this is naturally out of your control.

There is also a common pattern for some libraries to provide their own prelude: a module that re-exports symbols that are likely to be useful. `anyhow` does not provide one at the time of writing.

See also:

- [What is the prelude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384840/what-is-the-prelude)

---

¹Almost anything becomes possible with macros or another preprocessor, but it is hardly a good tradeoff for this case.

Comment: Of note: while anyhow does not provide a prelude, if there are symbols you use everywhere in a program you can have an "internal prelude" which re-exports all the relevant stuff (but is not itself exported in the case of a lib crate). Then, at the top of all your modules you can just `use crate::prelude::*` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Rust doesn't support global imports.

However, for global *macro* imports, there is a way, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70011610/15602349). That won't solve your problem completely, but it will at least allow you to avoid importing the macros.

In your `main.rs` you can add this:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate anyhow;
```

And then you can use macros like `bail!` and `ensure!` all around your project, without the need to explicitly import them.